# Phrase structure trees for different languages

Tags: syntax, grammar, phrase-structure

I am trying to get to the bottom of the difference between (1) and (2) below, and how the intended meanings would be reflected in a phrase structure tree:

(1) *If you think that $100 is too little you could give $150 just as well*

(2) ? *If you think that $100 is too little you should give $150 just as well*

The issue seems to be that *just as well* is within the scope (I am not sure of the right terminology here) of *could* and *should*. *Could* admits more than one possibility, so that’s fine, but *should* does not, so to express the intended meaning the *just as well* must be set off in its own clause:

(3) *If you think that $100 is too little, you should give $150; that would do just as well.*

(3) would presumably look quite different from (2) on a phrase structure tree, but where would *that would do just as well* attach?

Edit: I think the tree would look like this:

[image: Tree]

If (2) and (3) are equivalent in a given language, could this be accounted for by saying that in (2), *just as well* attaches to a different node in the tree than it does in English?

Edit: I now think that (1) and (2) may be parsed like the tree above in Thai, which puts the *just as well* outside the scope of the modal in both cases, meaning that it doesn't matter whether it is restrictive like *should* or unrestrictive like *could*.

If that's right, the question is whether it is the same phenomenon as in serial verbs. They both seem to be cases of backing up and attaching something higher up the tree without much in the way of an explicit instruction. In the sentences above, if you want the *just as well* to attach higher up in EN, you have to signal that explicitly, as in (3). Similarly, if the verb phrases in serial constructions like *go [and] see* are sister nodes, the difference is that EN won't let you get away with more than two without an *and* to signal that you need to go back up and branch across (rather than building downward) whereas in TH you can carry on to your heart's content. The idea that these two things are linked is only a hunch for the time being, as I haven't yet got to the bottom of whether the VPs in serial constructions are in fact sister nodes, or whether they cascade down (or whether the presence / absence of *and* makes any difference). I posted about that [here.](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/29973/phrase-structure-trees-for-serial-verb-constructions)

Comment: _Should_ is deontic and therefore doesn't make sense with the optionality of _just as well_. Just as well as **what**? It's an implied comparison, but there's nothing to compare with. And this is semantic, not syntactic; the sentences would have the same trees, however you arrange them.

Comment: Yes, that's where I was going with (3) - in order to get the intended meaning of (2) we have to rewrite the sentence, resulting in a different tree. But in Thai (my language of interest) (2) is grammatical and means the same as (3) - so they have different parsing rules. It struck me like the tree a Thai speaker recovers from (2) may well be like the one and EN speaker recovers from (3), so what I am interested in is the difference between the EN trees for (1) and (3).

Comment: BTW I believe the semantic issue is the same in both cases, and (2) would be ungrammatical in either language if parsed in the same way as (1). In EN we can only parse it that way, so we are stuck with an ungrammatical sentence, but in Thai it can evidently be parsed in such a way as to make sense, and I am very interested in this difference between the two languages.

Comment: Of course whether (2) is grammatical depends on how you translate it - you could argue that what I have translated as just as well should be instead - but just as well is more literal and I am interested in the idea that the difference is one of phrase structure. I expect it would be necessary to add a couple of things by implication, but the elememts you can imply into a sentence depend on the ways you parse / could parse it, so that may not turn out to be much of a problem.

Comment: I now have a tree (from an automatic parser) that seems to make sense of this.